# Jenkins NextGeneration Warnings plugin: publishIssues fails with there's no @DataBoundConstructor

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I am using a Jenkins pipeline file and i want to integrate the [cpd](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_cpd.html) tool. 
Therefore I am using the NextGenerationWarnings Plugin and followed their [docs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md#advanced-pipeline-configuration) (See section Advanced Pipeline configuration).

For testing purpose I added the call to the checkout stage.

**Stage:**

```
stage ("Checkout") {
            cleanWs()
            echo "Using branch $BRANCH_NAME"
            def gitResult = checkout(scm)
            echo "${gitResult}"
            def myworkspace = pwd()
            sh "/var/lib/jenkins/pmd-bin-6.12.0/bin/run.sh cpd -failOnViolation false --minimum-tokens 70 --files $myworkspace/PROG --language cpp --format xml > cpd.xml"
            def cpd = scanForIssues tool: cpd(pattern: 'cpd.xml')
            unzip publishIssues {issues: [cpd]}
        }
```

**Error:**

During Build I receive the following error message.

> [Pipeline] publishIssues
>
> [Pipeline] }
>
> [Pipeline] // stage
>
> [Pipeline] echo
>
> ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate
>   {issues=org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@2c319167} for
>   PublishIssuesStep(issues:
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: There's no
>   @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class
>   io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.steps.AnnotatedReport[],
>   failedNewAll?(deprecated): int, failedNewHigh?(deprecated): int,
>   failedNewLow?(deprecated): int, failedNewNormal?(deprecated): int,
>   failedTotalAll?(deprecated): int, failedTotalHigh?(deprecated): int,
>   failedTotalLow?(deprecated): int, failedTotalNormal?(deprecated): int,
>   healthy?: int, id?: String, ignoreFailedBuilds?: boolean,
>   ignoreQualityGate?: boolean, minimumSeverity?: String, name?: String,
>   qualityGates?: QualityGate(threshold: int, type:
>   QualityGateType[TOTAL, TOTAL_ERROR, TOTAL_HIGH, TOTAL_NORMAL,
>   TOTAL_LOW, NEW, NEW_ERROR, NEW_HIGH, NEW_NORMAL, NEW_LOW, DELTA,
>   DELTA_ERROR, DELTA_HIGH, DELTA_NORMAL, DELTA_LOW], unstable:
>   boolean)[], referenceJobName?: String, sourceCodeEncoding?: String,
>   unhealthy?: int, unstableNewAll?(deprecated): int,
>   unstableNewHigh?(deprecated): int, unstableNewLow?(deprecated): int,
>   unstableNewNormal?(deprecated): int, unstableTotalAll?(deprecated):
>   int, unstableTotalHigh?(deprecated): int,
>   unstableTotalLow?(deprecated): int, unstableTotalNormal?(deprecated):
>   int): java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.steps.PublishIssuesStep.issues
>   expects
>   java.util.List
>   but received class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2

I am not sure what the `@DataBoundConstructor` annotation does, but could that be related to an outdated java version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem.

I dont know why, but for some reason I added `unzip` and these `{}` around `publishIssues issues: [cpd]`.

Removing them, resolved my issue and now it works perfect.